# selectionchangeListener and ButtonEvent Listener

Tags: java, gxt

I have a button that updates data to a grid.I want to display a message box when grid is updated.So I wanted to invoke that in a selection change listener.Is that possible.Any other suggestions??

Comment: Have you tried it? Can you show us your attempt, preferably as a [SCCEE](http://sscce.org)? When you say "grid" what do you mean - a JTable perhaps?

Comment: Yes I am using a button events.onclick listener but I want that triggers the message message box immediately obv..I want it not trigger right away but only on migration

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a MessageBox when the Grid is updated. Then you can add StoreListener on the Grid's Store.

Example

```
  grid.getStore().addStoreListener(new StoreListener<ModelData>() {

    @Override
    public void storeUpdate(StoreEvent<ModelData> se) {
        MessageBox.alert(...);
    }

  });
```

Comment: Thanks...But now what I am trying to do is to show a message Box when a button is clicked ...but do not want it to fire right away...but only on navigation